Why middleware in Laravel 11 raise redirected you too many times error?
I try to refactor and move my code from Laravel 10 site to Laravel 11 / Livewire 3.5 site
and in app/Http/Middleware/CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware.php I have custom checks from Livewire 10:
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    \Log::info(' -1 CheckAuthPermissions auth()->check()::');
    if(!auth()->check())) {
        \Log::info(' -999 logout() CheckAuthPermissions auth()->check()::');
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect()->route('login')->with('status', 'Please log in to access this page.');
    }

    if (auth()->user()->status !== 'A') {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect()->route('login')->with('status', 'Please log in to access this page.');
    }

}

in routes/web.phpI control with this middleware:
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

Route::prefix('personal')->name('personal.')->middleware([CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware::class])->group(function () {
    Route::get('profile', ProfileEditor::class)->name('ProfileEditor');
});



Route::prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware([CheckAuthPermissionsMiddleware::class])->group(function () {
    Route::get('points/edit/{id?}', PointsController::Class)->name('Points');
    ...

But I got error :
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.

Checking log file I see a lot of lines like :
-1 CheckAuthPermissions auth()->check()::
...
-999 logout() CheckAuthPermissions auth()->check()::

What has changed in Laravel 11 and how to fix it ?
    "laravel/breeze": "^2.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
    "livewire/livewire": "^3.5",


It can sometimes happen if you do not have a route named login, because the auth middleware redirects to a named route by default the login route.
